# Ranking SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking

I'm making kind of top-ten ranking in my app, and I'm stuck in the SQL query that I'll use for that.
I have 2 tables.
The 'posts' table stores the ID of the post autor(user_id), and the post content(and, of course, the entry ID).

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| ID | user_id |   content    |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 |       3 | Lorem Ipsum1 |
|  2 |       6 | Lorem Ipsum2 |
|  3 |       3 | Lorem Ipsum3 |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

The 'likes' table, stores ID of the person who liked the post(user_id), the post ID(post_id) and the like date witch is a timestamp(like_date).

```
+----+---------+---------+------------+
| ID | user_id | post_id | like_date  |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
|  1 |       2 |       1 | 1491484851 |
|  2 |       5 |       1 | 1491484871 |
|  3 |      11 |       2 | 1491484891 |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
```

Every time a user like a post, an entry is created at the 'likes' table, and if the user unlike it, I just remove the entry.
And here's the deal. I want to grab the top 10 most liked users of the last 30 days. I want the query result to be something like this

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | likes |
+---------+-------+
|       3 |     2 |
|       6 |     1 |
+---------+-------+
```

I've already tried a tons of queries and spent a couple of hours trying to solve that, but I just cant figure out how to.

Comment: First of all, show your efforts. Then, you write "top 10 most liked posts" but your sample output shows `user_id`... which one do you want?

Comment: Sorry. I mean "users".

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: You can use `order by` and `limit` to show only the top 10.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "post_id" not "user_id" in your expected results:

```
SELECT post_id, count(*) as 'likes'
FROM likes
GROUP BY post_id
WHERE like_date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
ORDER By 2 desc
LIMIT 10
```

Everything's in the likes table, so filter recent posts (WHERE), return/order by the count and onl retrieve the first 10 rows. There are other ways to achieve this...

Comment: Yeah, I think I just have to get that result and sum the likes according with the post autor

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick

```
select  user_id, count(*)
from    posts t1
join    likes t2
on      t1.ID = t2.post_id
where   from_unixtime(t2.like_date) >= now() - interval 30 day
group by user_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a `join` for this:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as numlikes
FROM likes l
WHERE like_date >= unix_timestamp() - 30*24*60*60
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY numlikes desc
LIMIT 10;
```

The `like_date` looks like a Unix timestamp, so we should treat it as one.  This gets exactly 30 days from the current time to the second.  If you want to count days from midnight:

```
WHERE like_date >= unix_timestamp(CURDATE() - interval 30 day)
```

EDIT:

If it is the `user_id` from the post, then you would use `join` to get that:

```
SELECT p.user_id, count(*) as numlikes
FROM likes l join
     posts p
     on l.post_id = p.id
WHERE l.like_date >= unix_timestamp() - 30*24*60*60
GROUP BY p.user_id
ORDER BY numlikes desc
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: That will bring the total of likes that users gives, wouldn't?
I'm looking for the total of likes that a users received in that period